# How to get typescript metadata of a file?

Tags: typescript

I have these serverless microservices created using serverless framework. Everything works fine, but there are some annoying situations not related to serverless.

When some of my lambdas need to call another lambda I have a helper method that helps me to create lambda calls, to everything work fine, I need to pass the input and output typings, the lambda name and the service name. With the following structure I'm able to call this lambda anywhere I want, with the typechecking I need. I will call the following a **client**

```
export const createWallet = getLambda<CreateWalletEvent, Wallet>({
    lambdaShortName: 'createWallet',
    serviceName: 'bolico-wallets-svc'
});


export const populateWallets = getLambda<PopulateWalletsEvent, PopulateResultReponse>({
    lambdaShortName: 'populateWallets',
    serviceName: 'bolico-wallets-svc'
});
```

This format is working fine  with one exception. I Need to recreate all the typings for each microservice. Create those lambdas calls for each service is quite annoying, I need to export the typings, and populate a new `getLambda<T,R>` for each new lambda manually. So I want to create a script to generate the files I need.

All my lambda functions looks like the following I will call this **handler**:

```
export const handler = async (event: CreateWalletInput): Promise<Wallet> => {
    return walletService.createWallet(event);
}
```

So, What I need to do is  generate a **client** based on the **handler** with the proper types

*Is it possible read that **handler** or any  typescript file and get some sort of metadata?*

For the **handler** code for example, I would like to have a some sort of array:

```
[
    {
        type: "function",
        name: "handler",
        input: ["CreateWalletInput"],
        output: ["Promise<Wallet>"],
        exported: true,
    }
]
```

Does anyone knows about any library or tool  to get this kind of metadata? At this point I can think only about reading the file and trying to find some regexes to get what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [`ts-morph`](https://ts-morph.com/) would help?
It seems like they partially enable what you need, e.g. https://ts-morph.com/manipulation/structures. I'm not an expert -- you would need to read their README and documentation to see if it is a right tool for your needs ;)

Comment: Hello, Yes, I think this is the right path right now. Looks a bit complicated but I think it's what I need, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your situation calls for a tool that can extract certain tokens from the source code programmatically. Perhaps have a look at [`ts-morph`](https://ts-morph.com/navigation/example), which does the heavy-lifting behind the scenes on [ts-ast-viewer.com](https://ts-ast-viewer.com):

[image]

Hope that helps.